# Grails and Geb: Reproducible deletion test

Tags: grails, spock, geb

I want to test a simple CRUD deletion with Geb, Grails and RemoteControl.

Here my simplified code:

```
test "Delete a book"() {
    when:
    to BookShowPage // book/show/1
    deleteLink.click(BookListPage)

    then:
    // ...

    cleanup:
    def remote = new RemoteControl()
    remote {
        new Book(title:'title').save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
        return true
    }
}
```

But how can I make my test reproducible?

If I repeat my test, the new book will have another id and so test fails.

Comment: do your Book setup in a given: block and retrieve the ID of the Book, make the 'to BookShowPage' consume the ID of the Book added in the given block (I am assuming that you can do this, haven't ventured into Geb yet myself), and you should be replicable?

Comment: It's a good  way. I have only to discover hot to pass id to the geb page...
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to railsdog's comment, I resolved creating a new Book in the given block.

Here the right code:

```
test "Delete a book"() {
    given:
    def remote = new RemoteControl()
    def bookId = remote {
        Book book = new Book(title:'title').save(failOnError: true)
        return book.id
    }

    when:
    to BookShowPage, bookId // (*)
    deleteLink.click(BookListPage)

    then:
    // ...

    cleanup:
    remote {
        Book book = Book.get(bookId)
        if (book) { 
            // Test fails and we have junk into the db...
            book.delete(failOnError: true) 
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

(*) See [how to customize Geb page URL](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#advanced-page-navigation).